# .htaccess "Internal Server Error" when adding / to URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z]+) profile.php [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But you can't add a `/` to the end of the URL. For example if you goto `something` it works but `something/` doesn't. So how do I allow a `/` to be added to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution if anyone else is having the same problem (not fully tested but seems to work).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z]+) profile.php [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(/.*)?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Does it really work for you? The rule you posed as solution rewrites `/something/foobar` to  `something.php` .

Comment: As AmitVerma suggests, this does not strictly do what you were asking in the question? If you are only dealing with "extensionless URLs" then this potentially opens up your server for abuse, unless you are later parsing the requested URL (although your question does not suggest this)? eg. `/file/keyword-abuse-spam-pron-etc`. However, this also won't successfully rewrite a request of the form `/subdir/file` (where `subdir` is a physical subdirectory), as it will attempt to rewrite the request to `/subdir.php` and 404 - if that is a concern?

Answer (score -1):

To allow the trailing slash in URLs that point to your `php` files, replace your last rule with this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

`/?` matches the slash as an optional character so your rule will also match URIs not ending with a `/` .

Comment: You'll need to make the capturing group non-greedy, otherwise it will capture the _optional_ trailing slash and you'll have the same problem. eg. `^(.*?)/?$`. Or, it may be sufficient to capture everything excluding a slash (if `something` is only a single path segment.).

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for pointing this out. But Regex is not greedy when used in `RewriteRule`  It might behave like that if  used  in `RewriteCond` .

Comment: @AmitVerma "Regex is not greedy when used in `RewriteRule`" - Yes it is! The quantifiers `*` and `+` are always "greedy", wherever they are used in Apache (PCRE) regex (hence the need to make them non-greedy with `*?` and `+?` respectively in this instance).